# Rxjs observables reducing

Tags: rxjs, observable

I'm working on processing of a string, but some functions are observables, so I'm trying to figure out an easy way to do this.

Say i have the following class:

```
class Something {
  doSomething(input: string): Observable<string> {
    return of('123 - ' + input);
  }
}
```

where the `of('123 - ' + input)` is some service (like http.get()) that's been called and returns a string.

And I'd like to append each result of a service to the result of the next one, until the last is reached.
But I have no clue on how to do this.

Latest what I've got was the following:

```
return of(
  new Something(),
  new Something(),
  new Something(),
)
  .pipe(
    reduce(
      (acc, curr, i) => {
        console.log('NEXT', acc);
        if(!(curr instanceof Observable)){
          acc = of(acc);
        }
        return acc.pipe(map(c => curr.doSomething(c)));
      },
      'Start string: '
  );
```

this would then result in `Start string: 123 - 123 - 123 -`, but this is not the case. and I'm running out of idea's to get this working

Here is a basic stackblitz to get started, if you'd like to try some things:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-htcna8?file=index.ts

Comment: Do these calls need to run in series or can they be run in parallel?

Comment: @IngoBürk call A's result is needed in call B and then passed on in C, ... so in serie :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out you can do the following:

```
const source = [
  new Something(),
  new Something(),
  new Something(),
  new Something()
];

let chain = source[0].doSomething('Initial string');
source.splice(0, 1);

source.forEach(r => {
  chain = chain.pipe(
    switchMap(s => r.doSomething(s))
  );
});
```

Comment: Am I right in thinking `let chain = Observable.of('Initial string');` removes the need to `splice`?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want `mergeScan`:

```
const source = [
  new Something(),
  new Something(),
  new Something(),
  new Something()
];

from(source).pipe(
  // Scan over all the inner streams passing each result to the next call
  mergeScan((acc, s) => s.doSomething(acc), '', 1),
  // The above emits partial results, so ignore all except the last one.
  last()
).subscribe(console.log);

// Expected output: 123 - 123 - 123 - 123
```

Docs [here](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js%7EObservable.html#instance-method-mergeScan)

> Applies an accumulator function over the source Observable where the accumulator function itself returns an Observable, then each intermediate Observable returned is merged into the output Observable.
>
> > It's like scan, but the Observables returned by the accumulator are merged into the outer Observable.

Comment: Awesome! thanks. this is what I needed, this even works better then my own 'solution'

Answer (score -1):

Because i'am not sure about what you expect, i have prepare 3 cases for you :

```
// Expected output: One next with ["123 - 1", "123 - 2", "123 - 3", "123 - 4"]
forkJoin(source).subscribe(val => console.log(val));

// Expected output: Many next with : 
// * 123 - 1
// * 123 - 2
// * 123 - 3
// * 123 - 4
forkJoin(source).pipe(concatAll()).subscribe(val => console.log(val));

// Expected output : One next with string "123 - 1, 123 - 2, 123 - 3, 123 - 4"
forkJoin(source).pipe(map((e) => {
  return e.join(', ');
})).subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Sample : https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-s3yr3h?file=index.ts

Comment: Thanks!, but i forgot to mention that i want to use the result of my last method in the next one